# Lavaan and semPlot - semPaths Error in `colnames<-`

Tags: r, r-lavaan, structural-equation-model

I'm trying to run the following SEM model with ordinal data:

```
model.IAQ.TH.APP = '
OVERALL=~Q1+Q2+Q4
IAQ=~Q19+Q20+Q21+Q22
THERMAL=~Q13+Q14+Q15+Q17
APPEARANCE=~Q34+Q35+Q36+Q37+Q38
OVERALL~IAQ+THERMAL+APPEARANCE+BECHTEL+IOEC
'

model.IAQ.TH.APP.fit <- sem(model.IAQ.TH.APP, data = mydata,     std.lv=TRUE,fixed.x=TRUE, ordered = c("Q1","Q2", "Q4", "Q19","Q20", "Q21","Q22","Q13","Q14","Q15","Q17","Q34","Q35","Q36","Q37","Q38"))
semPaths(model.IAQ.TH.APP.fit, whatLabels = "std", layout = "tree")
summary(model.IAQ.TH.APP.fit, standardized=TRUE, rsquare=TRUE, fit.measures = TRUE)
```

Note that BECHTEL and IOEC are dummy variables (0/1) introduced to specify in which building the data has been collected and to see the relationship between the building and the OVERALL satisfaction. 
Now the fit is working with no error however when I'm trying to plot the model I'm getting the following error:

```
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("Q1", "Q2", "Q4", "Q19", "Q20",  : 
  attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions
```

I checked my original data file and it doesn't look wrong. Also when I try to run the model without specifying that the variables are ordinal it runs fine but I'm not sure it gives valid results (my variables are on 1-5 scale).

Could anyone please help me with this problem?

Thanks